# Is there a source that provides data for the temperature coefficient of resistivity at different temperatures?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm looking for a source where I can find the temperature coefficient of resistivity at different temperatures for pure metals.  Tables are everywhere for 20$\,^{\circ}$C, but I'm having difficulties finding data for other temperatures.

One resource I looked at (http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=546194) provides a formula:

$\alpha_T = \left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha_0} + T}\right)$

I don't believe that's applicable to all materials, but is there a group of materials where that expression is true?

---

**[UPDATE]**

@Trimok led me to the Bloch–Grüneisen formula

$\rho(T)=\rho(0)+A\left(\frac{T}{\Theta_R}\right)^n\int_0^{\frac{\Theta_R}{T}}\frac{x^n}{(e^x-1)(1-e^{-x})}dx$

I can work with that, but there's a lot of parameters that I would need before solving it.  Is there a source for $\rho\left(0\right)$, $A$, $\Theta_R$  (the Debye temperature), for different metals?  Also which of the n values need to be considered?

Comment: In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity), section Temperature dependence/Metals, you will see the Bloch–Grüneisen formula.

Comment: in [Debye temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_temperature), you have some indications. The signification of $n$ is given in the previous comment ref : $n = 5$ for scattering of electrons by phonons , $n = 3$ for s-d electron scattering , $n=2$ for electron–electron interaction .I think $n=5$ could be choosen. The qualitative definition of $\rho(0)$ and $A$ are also given in previous comment ref: $\rho(0)$ is the residual resistivity due to defect scattering and is essentially temperature independent.The definition of $A$ is more complex.

Comment: Maybe some [images](https://www.google.fr/search?q=Bloch%E2%80%93Gr%C3%BCneisen&biw=1280&bih=872&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=GWm7UbvpNYnPObrCgJgF&ved=0CDQQsAQ)  will  lead you to an interesting reference ?